# I cannot set Safe Args default value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-safe-args

I have a `String` type arg send from `NewCodeFragment` to `MainFragment`.

If I set a default value, then I got a 'too many args' error.

How can I set a default value? My understanding is if I send a arg, then the destination fragment will receive the arg, else it will receive the default value. Wrong?

**Problem code:**

`navigation` XML:

```
<argument
    android:name="aArg"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true"
    android:defaultValue="@null" />
```

`fragment.class` :

```
val aArg="abc"      
// build error, it says too many args    
this.findNavController().navigate(NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment(aArg))
```

**No problem code:**

`navigation` XML:

```
<argument
    android:name="aArg"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true"/>     // remove android:defaultValue="@null"
```

`fragment.class` :

```
val aArg="abc"      
this.findNavController().navigate(NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment(aArg))
```

**Another no problem code:**

`navigation` XML:

```
<argument
    android:name="aArg"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true"
    android:defaultValue="@null" />
```

`fragment.class` :

```
val aArg="abc"      
this.findNavController().navigate(NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment())   // remove aArg
```

Answer (score 3):

If your fragment parameter has a default value the generated builder method will not have parameter for it. You will need to set the value of that fragment parameter separately on the xDirections object. There should be a method to set each parameter. For your example to work you will need to do something like if using Java:

```
String aArg = "abc";
NewCodeFragmentDirections.ActionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment direction = 
    NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment().aArg(aArg);
this.findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

In Kotlin this may look something like:

```
this.findNavController().navigate(
    NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment().apply {
        aArg = "abc"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the last approach. Here argument can have default value. If you have a standard value instead of passing it in the argument my suggestion would be you keep it in the destination fragment that will receive the arguments. So, you won't have to add the same default string everywhere. If the `defaultValue` from `args` is `null`, you can use the value on that fragment.

```
<argument
    android:name="aArg"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true"
    android:defaultValue="@null" />
```

For example, 3 Fragments A, B and C are going Fragment X with args. A passes `"abc"`, B and C pass `null`. Now you can have the condition in Fragment X when reading from the args,

```
val aArgument = safeArgs.aArg?.let {
    // Use it
    it
} else {
    // Use the default String
    "This is your default string"
}
```

Comment: My problem is with default value, I cannot pass "abc" anymore, it got a 'too many args' error as case 1 in my topic.

Comment: In my case 3, you see I have to remove aArg  to eliminate the building error, in that case, how can I pass aArg to destination? I would always pass default value forever.

Comment: @caibirdcnb - Did you try rebuilding the project after changing the arguments? Because navigations arguments need project rebuild after changing, else it takes the previously generated code.

Comment: @caibirdcnb Use approach 1 and rebuild project. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I did tried rebuild, I've also tried invalidate caches /restart, but no lucky.

Comment: I have the same code and it works. I hope you added arguments to all the navigation actions where you are going to NewCodeFragment.

Comment: This might help https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188855904

Answer (score 0):

There must be generated method for setting value. As on authors example must be like this:

```
val aArg="abc"
val action = NewCodeFragmentDirections.actionNewCodeFragmentToMainFragment.setAArg(aArg)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```